# Links redirecting to wrong view path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

All links work well except for devise. If I try to click sign up or log in it takes me to the sign up/log in page, right?

From the URL it looks normal. `localhost:3000/users/sign_up` but the view is wrong. It's displaying the profile view instead of the devise sign up/log in view.

[image]

Routes code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :questions

  get '/users/:id' => 'profile#profile'
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
end
```

Profile controller:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  def profile
  end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

It didn't do that at first, I think this bug happened when I edited the show.html.erb view in the questions folder.

Show code (question):

```
<% @questions.each do |q| %>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <% if q.id == current_user.id %>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(@question) %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Question controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @questions = Question.all
    respond_with(@questions)
  end

  def show
    @questions = Question.all
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question.save
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  def update
    @question.update(question_params)
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  private
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:title, :description, :image_url)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting that `get '/users/:id' => 'profile#profile'` below the `devise_for :users` line.

Comment: Ordering in `config/routes.rb` file matters in Rails. I think devise already has claims on the `users/:id` path, so it was overriding your `profile` path.